# SAS Creating a count variable that resets

Tags: sas

I'd like to create a count variable that resets every 6 months by the manner of crime.  Here is my code :

```
proc sort data=incident_v1;
by incident year;
run;

Data incident_v2;
set incident_v1 end= eof;
by incident;
do i=1 until (eof);

do j = 1 to 6;
          retain ID 0;
if first.incident then  ID=ID +1;
end;

         end;
                    run;
```

Year-mo incident    # of incidents  Count  every six months
199901  car-jack    6                  1
199902  car-jack    7                  2
199903  car-jack    12                 3
199904  car-jack    8                  4
199905  car-jack    13                 5
199906  car-jack    8                  6
199907  car-jack    13                 1
199908  car-jack    6                  2
199909  car-jack    8                  6
200001  robbery         5                      1
200002  robbery     5                  2
200003  robbery         8                  3
200004  robbery         4                  4
200005  robbery         6                  5
200006  robbery        14                  6

Comment: It's hard to answer a question which has formatting issues. If you fix your formatting you're much more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
proc sort data=incident_v1;
by incident year;
run;

Data incident_v2;
 set incident_v1 end= eof;
 by incident;
 /*Reset Count if New Incident Type*/
 if first.incident then Incident_count_6_mnths = 0;
 /*Reset Count if month is 07 (which from your data below I believe to be actually year & month and of the form YYYYMM*/
 if substr(year,5,2) = "07" then Incident_count_6_mnths = 0; 
 /*if year is a not a text field you will have to use: substr(compress(put(year,8.)),5,2) = "07" */

 /*Add a counter - please note there is no need for a retain statement as the +1 will automatically retain.*/
 Incident_count_6_mnths+1;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you. If I want to create new counter for every row by manner and year(year-month) , how would I alter the code you have provided. I need to calculate a moving rate.